# Cardinality of a set-NBHM 2005

Tags: analysis

let $f\colon [0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be continuous and such that $f(0)=f(1)$. Let $$A=\{\,(t,s)\in [0,1]\times [0,1] ;t\neq s;f(t)=f(s)\,\}$$

How to find the number of elements of $A$? Is there any theorem which can help me here?

Answer (score 3):

The theorem that helps is the Intermediate Value Theorem.

> If $f$ is constant, then $A$ is the unit square minus the diagonal, hence $|A|=\mathfrak c$. If $f$ is not constant, then for any of the $\mathfrak c$-many $y$ between $\min f$ and $\max f$ there are at least two distict points $s,t$ with $f(s)=f(t)=y$. Hence again $|A|\ge \mathfrak c$. Since trivially $|A|\le \mathfrak c$, we always have $|A|=\mathfrak c$.

Comment: can u please explain a bit more

Comment: The case when $f$ is not constant is not clear

Comment: Draw a unit square and draw any $f$ st $f(0)=f(1)$ you'll see that there are uncountably many lines parallel to x axis which are going to intersect $f$ atleast at two points and these two points are your $s$ and $t$ i.e there are uncountably many $(s,t)$ st $s\neq t$ and $f(s)=f(t)$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: How do you say $\textbf{atleast two distinct points}$? IVP (between min and max) allows us to say atleast one. I know this is true by looking at a graph. I also understand that the function is concave up or concave down atleast once (not necessary both). I am able to see it visually. But how to say $\textbf{atleast two distinct points}$ mathematically?

Comment: @Bhauryal: Can you help me out with this "$\textbf{atleast two distinct points}$"? IVP (between min and max) allows us to say atleast one. I know this is true by looking at a graph. I also understand that the function is concave up or concave down atleast once (not necessary both). I am able to see it visually. But how to say $\textbf{atleast two distinct points}$ mathematically?